# Does tuple_size count the elements in the tuple like lists:length()?

Tags: erlang

Is there ever a reason where I would do something like:

```
{foobar, NumberOfElementsInFoobarTuple, ...}
```

I would imagine the internal datastructure for tuple_size knows it's size already, like the binary type. With binaries it's still beneficial to keep track of byte size as a variable instead of calling byte_size(). It doesn't make sense but that's how it is. I'm creating this tuple through list_to_tuple so it may have varying size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A tuple is **one** fixed size block compared to a list which is a linked list of *list cells* each of which has a *head* and a *tail*. So a tuple explicitly contains its size and `tuple_size(Tuple)` just directly returns this value.